# $\mathbb{E}[e^{ t \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 }] = \Pi_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[e^{tX_i^2}]$

Tags: probability

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{ t \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 }] = \Pi_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[e^{tX_i^2}]$$

How do I get this?

[image]

It seems like in here, $\mathbb{E}[y_1+y_2+...] = \mathbb{E}[y_1]\mathbb{E}[y_2]...$

Comment: First of all,
$$\exp\left(t\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right) \neq \sum_{i=1}^n\exp(tX_i^2)$$
because it's actually
$$\exp\left(t\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n\exp(tX_i^2)$$
which follows from basic exponent properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Note that 
   $$e^{t\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2}=e^{t X_1^2}\cdot\ldots\cdot e^{t X_n^2}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n e^{t X_i^2}
   $$
2. For any tuple $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ of independent random variables  we have
   $$
   \mathbb{E}\left[\prod\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i\right]
   =\mathbb{E}[Y_1\cdot\ldots\cdot Y_n]
   =\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\cdot\ldots\cdot\mathbb{E}[Y_n]
   =\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[Y_i]
   $$
3. It is remains to set $Y_i=e^{t X_i^2}$ to get
   $$
   \mathbb{E}\left[e^{t\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2}\right]=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[e^{t X_i^2}]
   $$
4. Since $X_i$ are identically distributed, then $\mathbb{E}[e^{t X_i^2}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{t X_1^2}]$, so we get
   $$
   \mathbb{E}\left[e^{t\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2}\right]=\mathbb{E}[e^{t X_1^2}]^n
   $$